# Convert numeric time value to string in Netezza

Tags: sql, string, timestamp, netezza

I'm trying to convert a date key and a time key (both numeric) to a timestamp in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format in Netezza.

e.g. date_key=20120711  time_key=61946 should be converted to '2012-07-11 06:19:46'

I tried to_date function

```
to_date(date_key||to_char(time_key,'099999'),'yyyymmdd hh24miss').
```

The function works in Oracle but fails in Netezza only producing a date result: '2012-07-11 00:00:00' for the above example. What would work in Netezza? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That logic works however in `Netezza` you need to call the `to_timestamp` function to include time.

```
select test.datekey
, to_timestamp( test.datekey||trim(to_char(test.timekey,'099999')),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
, to_timestamp( test.datekey||to_char(test.timekey,'099999'),'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS')
from (select cast(20120711 as integer) as datekey, cast(61946 as integer) as timekey ) as test
```

Comment: It's worth noting that what Oracle refers to as a DATE is actually stored internally as what we would think of as a TIMESTAMP, and that's why the to_date function works as it does in Oracle.